# How to validate input field (username) to not allow whitespaces in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I have a username field in a form, I want to validate it by not allowing whitespaces in it like it should not accept a username like 'abc xyz'.

Comment: Use `pattern` and specify a regex of allowed characters.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Model` rules use something like :

```
['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/i']
```

Comment: yes I can understand this regular expression but after * '$/i' i am not getting

Comment: @SamiUllahShah [Read Explanation on Right](https://regex101.com/r/2aK82P/2)

Comment: Why do you use i flag when you've already included capital letters in pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,50}" title="Letters numbers">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Or use event in javascript

```
 <input type="text" name="username" onkeydown="myFunction()">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Comment: Using client side validation is fine and it's convenient for end users. But using only client side validation is not enough. You should always combine it with server side validation because client side validation can be modified/evaded.